# Outlook Plain-Text Viewer

Tags: microsoft-outlook, plaintext

How can I view the plain text part of a message in Outlook.  Or, rather, since that's actually impossible, is there a plugin or standalone app I can drag a msg into, to see what the plain text part of an email contains?

I'm trying to verify some email sent from lyris, that the plain text contains the correct text, and will appear as I want, BUT of course, Outlook, even if I change the options to view msgs as plain text, doesn't show you the plain text part of a multipart message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et010905.htm) on About.com should help you. It looks like it covers Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007:

In summary:

1. Open registry editor <kbd>Start</kbd> -> Run -> `regedit` -> <kbd>OK</kbd>
2. Go to the following entry

   - Outlook 2003: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook\Options\Mail`
   - Outlook 2007: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Options\Mail`
   - Outlook 2010: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Options\Mail`
   - Outlook 2013: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Options\Mail`
   - Outlook 2016: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Options\Mail`
3. On the menu bar, select `Edit` -> `New` -> `DWord`

   - For 32-bit Office, select `DWORD(32-bit) Value`
   - For 64-bit Office, select `DWORD(64-bit) Value`
4. Type `SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders`
5. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. On the menu bar, select `Edit` -> `Modify`
7. Type `1`
8. Click <kbd>OK</kbd>
9. Close the registry editor
10. Restart Outlook if it has been running

[image]

[image]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work.  
I've got outlook 2003.  
Added the key at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\­­Software\­­Microsoft\­­Office\­­11.0\­­Outlook\­­Options\­­Mail
Set SaveAllMIMENotJustHeaders to 1.
Restarted Outlook.
Waited for a new email.
And the Options->Internet headers: still just shows the headers

Comment: I've just tried this on a computer that didn't have it enabled - Windows XP, Outlook 2003 SP3. I've updated my answer with some screenshots to illustrate what I did and that it worked. Make sure what you see in regedit is similar to my screenshot (Status Bar, Value Type etc...).

Comment: Still not showing, perhaps because it's going through exchange and it's messing it up rather than the client?

Comment: Yes, that would explain it. I don't have any experience with Exchange so I'm not sure what else to suggest. There's a relevant thread here: http://help.lockergnome.com/office/Outlook-2007-Full-Message-Source--ftopict978491.html

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer, since it'll likely help some people.

Unfortunately, my situation is different.  Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Thanks. :) You could edit your question to include the fact that it's an Exchange problem, or create that as a new question - someone else might have more ideas/workarounds.